# PCL: How to remove a specific cluster from IndicesClusterPtr?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I extract a subcloud from a pointcloud using ConditionalEuclideanClustering (according to tutorial). `IndicesClusterPtr` is of type `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>>`. Adding elements seems to work. I can't get the ith cluster removed from `clusters`. Can you give me a hint?

```
    pcl::IndicesClustersPtr clusters(new pcl::IndicesClusters);
    clusters->push_back( (*clusters2)[j])   //seems to be okay

    clusters->erase(i); // Nope
    (*clusters).erase(i); // Nope

    pcl::PointIndices empty_indices;   // compiles but results not as expected
    (*clusters)[i] = empty_indices;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an iterator as input. So call the `erase` function like this:

```
clusters->erase(clusters->begin()+i);
```